# Display ajax posted array in codeigniter view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to display objects of an array in a view that has been posted to controller from another view.

**Jquery ajax call**

`details` is an array with few objects

```
$(document).ready(function () { // working
    $("#nxt").click(function() {
        var tmp = details;
        var more_details = JSON.stringify(tmp);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/application/index.php/Welcome/detailsLoad',
            data: {more_details : more_details },
            success : function(){
                console.log('Posted');
                location.href="http://localhost/application/index.php/Welcome/detailsLoad"
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });    
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function detailsLoad()
{
        $moreDetails= $this->input->post('more_details');
        $this->load->view('simulation',$moreDetails);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
      foreach($moreDetails['more_details'] as $result) {
          echo $result['object1'], '<br>';
          echo $result['object2'], '<br>';
      }
?>
```

help me to modify and fix this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to data from the ajax call to move from your controller to your view you should set the name of the variable to be used inside your view:

```
$data = [];
$data['moreDetails'] = $this->input->post('more_details');
$this->load->view('simulation',$data);
```

Then you can use the variable `$moreDetails` inside the view:

```
foreach ($moreDetails as $result) {
    echo $result['object1'], '<br>';
    echo $result['object2'], '<br>';
}
```

Comment: error Message: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: You can try to use `var_dump($moreDetails);` to see the content of the variable. If you don't supply `Array` you will not be able to loop through it.

Comment: Are you sure that "`details` is an array with few objects"?

Comment: Did you check it in the console inside the run of `$("#nxt").click` ?